# Como colocar 2 condições no mesmo if?

Tags: javascript

```
if (velocidade1>=80 <100){
    alert("Velocidade alta, considere diminuir!")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para colocar duas condições no mesmo `if` basta utilizar o operador `and`

```
if (velocidade1>=80 && velocidade1 <100){ 
    alert("Velocidade alta, considere diminuir!")
}
```

Comment: como eu faço perguntas usando essa caixa de dialogo ? valeu !!

Comment: Não entendi. Qual pergunta? Qual caixa de diálogo?

Comment: minha pergunta ta toda junta na mesma linha , a sua resposta ta dentro de uma box cinza bem organizada , sacou ?

Comment: Ah, para isso basta utilizar o menu de composição de pergunta, apertar no botão `{ }` amostra de código.